# Is it supposed to be Johns game or John's game?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, apostrophe

I am confused between these two and wanted to know which sentence to use:

> 1)I was working as a developer on Johns game.
>
> 2)I was working as a developer on John's game.

From the little research that I did, it seems like I need to go with the first one. Because John's basically means "John is". Kindly let me know if I am correct and which one should I go with.

**More context.**

John is the name of a company/owner of the game.

Comment: Yes the name of the game is not John. Could you put that in as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your edit providing additional context, it is now clear that you would use the possessive form:

> I was working as a developer on John's game.

The use of apostrophe "s" can indicate the possessive, as in this case, or a contraction of "John is," as in the following example:

> John's a great friend to have.

Answer (score 3):

If the game belongs to, was created by, is associated with, etc. *John*, then it calls for a possessive which is known as the [genitive case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case). Because English does not decline nouns for case, it is necessary to add *'s* as a marker of possession.

If you were to write it as *Johns game*, then it would imply that the name of the game is *Johns*.

And as you've mentioned, *John's* can less commonly indicate a [contraction of *is*](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/troublesome-contractions-eg-idve) (i.e. proper noun + is), but this is generally only appropriate in [informal](http://www.writersdigest.com/editor-blogs/questions-and-quandaries/grammar/contractions-with-proper-nouns-brians-a-baseball-fan) speech and writing.